# Calling SiteCatalyst Data Insertion API from IIS web server

Tags: analytics, iis, logging

I'm new to IIS. How do I configure IIS to invoke my code to process the access log information in real time? Is there a better solution than reading the log file as it's written? Apache, for instance, has a TransferLog directive that will pipe the log to an external program.

My goal is to send web service usage data to SiteCatalyst using their Data Insertion API. This requires building an XML message with info from the access log (url, source IP address, timestamp) and posting the message to a SiteCatalyst url for incorporation with our other web usage statistics. I can do this in the Java code in my app server, but there are firewalls between my app server and the internet that make this solution administratively complicated.

There is a related question on stackoverflow, but the solution doesn't fit my use case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9749085/is-there-a-real-time-iis-trafic-viewer-or-way-to-progamatically-get-it-via-c/24821463

Comment: I don't think you can do this without programming

Comment: I agree. I expect to write code, but I'm looking for how to configure IIS to invoke my code.